# What is a Special Prime Number™?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

<sub>This is inspired by the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, now with numbers.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Special Prime Number™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

| A Special Prime Number™ | Not a Special Prime Number™ |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 7 |
| 83 | 101 |
| 283 | 313 |
| 5503 | 6397 |
| 7883 | 7901 |

Why are these called Special Prime Numbers™?

CSV version:

```
A Special Prime Number™, Not a Special Prime Number™
11,7
83,101
283,313
5503,6397
7883,7901
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are Special Prime because they are

> [Super-prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-prime), namely prime-indexed primes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is

> The special primes are the n:th prime, where n is odd. The non-special primes are the n:th prime where n is even.
>  F ex 11 is the 5th prime, 83 is the 23th prime... And 7 is the 4:th prime, 101 is the 26:th prime etc..